# Install module by apt-get, cannot import python package

Tags: python, import, package, google-colaboratory

I am trying to install *minieigen* python3 package in google colab.
I've been trying to install it through pip but there is lot of dependancies and after few hours of trying figure out what else is missing, I just gave up.

There is second option to install it using apt-get - `apt-get install python3-minieigen`. That one is fine, but I cannot import it in python later on. I've checked sys.path and it looks ok. [Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdUkY.png) is screenshot with path of installed package and sys.path.

Here is the snippet with commands that I am using:

```
!apt-get install python3-minieigen
!pip install minieigen
import minieigen
import sys
sys.path
```

I would appreciate any way of installing this package on google colab.

Comment: Can you please help with what document you are following?

Comment: Here is pypi [minieigen pypi](https://pypi.org/project/minieigen/)
[git repo](https://github.com/eudoxos/minieigen) and [ubuntu package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/python3-minieigen)